# How to add values to an HashSet based on its content without allocating a new HashSet

Tags: c#, collections, hashset

I'm trying to add values into an `HashSet<string>` based to its content.

I would love the code to look like this:

```cs
public static void AddModifiedValues(HashSet<string> properties)
{
    if (properties is null)
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (var element in properties)
    {
        result.Add(element + "id");
    }
}
```

The problem here is that I obviously get an exception as I'm modifying the collection I'm iterating on.

The current code ends up looking like this:

```cs
//different signature
public static HashSet<string> AddModifiedValues(HashSet<string> properties)
{
    //allocation
    var result = new HashSet<string>();
    if (properties is null)
    {
        return result;
    }

    foreach (var element in properties)
    {
        result.Add(element);
        result.Add(element + "id");
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is there a way to do what I'm looking for without allocating a new HashSet?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do that with Hashset type.

One of the reasons is you can't track where old values in collection ( in this case set ) end as every insert to hashet causes side effect internally.

However with List it is possible.

```
var properties = new List<string>()
{
  "test1",
  "test2"
};

var length = properties.Count;

for(var i = 0 ; i < length ; i++) {
  properties.Add(properties[i] + "id");
}
```

--Edit

Looks like I was wrong and [HashSet doesnt sort collection after inserting](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,188b8f94f8fc999b) so what you can do is to use [ElementAt](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,7db56d44563d8761) to access element.

```
var properties = new HashSet<string>()
{
  "test1",
  "test2"
};

var length = properties.Count;

for(var i = 0 ; i < length ; i++) {
  properties.Add(properties.ElementAt(i) + "id");
}
```

Comment: Or `properties.Add(properties.ElementAt(i) + "id");` using the original `HashSet`

Comment: Updated answer. Thank you!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `ElementAt` is a LINQ extension method, not a method from the class, so I suspect your edited version that uses this method to be O(n²), which I'm trying to avoid as well of course.

Comment: Yes, `ElementAt` approach would be O(n^2) as everytime it would do internally `GetEnumerator()`, `MoveNext()` until index matches with incremented iterator